# How to execute async code on DispatcherQueue (WinUI) without using async void?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, winui-3

I currently have some code to help execute async code on the main thread using `DispatcherQueue` in a WinUI 3 application using .Net 7.

```cs
// Note that this is a simplified version of the original code, for brevity.
public static async Task Execute(this DispatcherQueue dispatcher, Func<Task> function)
{
  if (dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
  {
    await function();
  }
  else
  {
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    dispatcher.TryEnqueue(ExecuteUI);
    await taskCompletionSource.Task;
  }

  static async void ExecuteUI()
  {
    try
    {
      await function();
      taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**What would be the best way to implement this feature without using `async void`?**

---

**Edit:**

I understand that the `DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue` overloads take `Action` or `Func` parameters that are not returning `Task`. My question in about about bridging that *sync-to-async* gap with a solution that complies with [this rule](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/threading_rules.md#rule-4-never-define-async-void-methods-make-the-methods-return-task-instead).

> Rule #4. Never define `async void` methods. Make the methods return `Task` instead.
>
> - Exceptions thrown from `async void` methods always crash the process.
> - Callers don't even have the option to `await` the result.
> - Exceptions can't be reported to telemetry by the caller.
> - It's impossible for your VS package to responsibly block in `Package.Close` till your `async` work is done when it was kicked off this way.
> - Be cautious: `async delegate` or `async () =>` become `async void`
>   methods when passed to a method that accepts `Action` delegates. Only
>   pass `async` delegates to methods that accept `Func<Task>` or
>   `Func<Task<T>>` parameters.

Comment: Something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.dispatcherqueueextensions.enqueueasync?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.1)? [Source](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/6bfe8a5d21feb8818a8048b9fc41a84a70af8b0f/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/Extensions/DispatcherQueueExtensions.cs#L18) if you want to take a look to implement something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> My question in about about bridging that sync-to-async gap with a solution that complies with this rule.

The [referenced rule](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/threading_rules.md#rule-4-never-define-async-void-methods-make-the-methods-return-task-instead) is specifically for developing Visual Studio extensions. To quote from ["Do I need to follow these rules?"](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/threading_rules.md#do-i-need-to-follow-these-rules):

> All code that runs in Visual Studio itself should follow these rules.
>
> Any other GUI app that invokes asynchronous code that it must occasionally block the UI thread on is also recommended to follow these rules.

For context, Visual Studio extensions should never use `async void` because there's Task-returning equivalents for everything in that system.

The general-purpose recommendation for non-Visual Studio code is [avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#avoid-async-void), which is much less strict. Specifically, `async void` *is* the proper solution for event handlers or logically equivalent code.

It might be stretching a bit, but you could look at `DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue` as a kind of manual event firing (from another thread). So I don't see anything wrong with `async void` here.

> I understand that the DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue overloads take Action or Func parameters that are not returning Task.

This is the API you're given, so it's what you have to work with.

There's only two real solutions: use `async void` or block (on the UI thread). Given the two, `async void` is far superior.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.WinUI) NuGet package and use one of the overloads of the `EnqueueAsync` method that accept a `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>`.

The source code for these methods are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/Extensions/DispatcherQueueExtensions.cs).

Comment: From what I understand, the code you referenced also uses `async void` [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/Extensions/DispatcherQueueExtensions.cs#L165) and [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/Extensions/DispatcherQueueExtensions.cs#L228) so it doesn't really answer the question; it's just hiding the `async void` in an external package.

Comment: What is the question then? The task gets awaited and any exception is propagated as expected. You cannot change the dispatcher API itself.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I've edited my question by adding more details about the rule I'm trying to comply to.

Comment: It's possible that there might not be a better alternative for this scenario and that we're reaching the limits of the best practices. I don't know; that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: The last bullet says "Only pass async delegates to methods that accept `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>` parameters." That's exactly what you do when you use the overloads in the `CommunityToolkit.WinUI` package. You can't do any better because of the implementation of the actual `DispatcherQueue`.